# How to pass query directly to the where condition?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

- Get `technology_id` from another query. It through an error.
- Is there any way to shorten the query.(nested query)

Query:

```
Vendor.where(vendors: {company: nil}).joins(technologies_vendors: {technology_id: "Technology.select(:technology_id).where(url: 'ios',is_verified: true)"})
```

error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'technology_id' was not found on TechnologiesVendor; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you've got three models set up with the following relationships:

```
Vendor has_many technologies_vendors
Technology has_many technologies_vendors
TechnologiesVendor belongs_to vendor
TechnologiesVendor belongs_to technology
```

Your conditions are:

```
vendors should have 'nil' company
technologies should be verified and have 'ios' url
```

In that case, this is what you want:

```
Vendor.
joins(technologies_vendors: :technology).
where({
  vendors: {company: nil},
  technologies: {url: 'ios', is_verified: true}
})
```

But you can quite easily use the `merge` method as well.

```
Vendor.
joins(technologies_vendors: :technology).
where(vendors: {company: nil}).
merge( Technology.where(technologies: {url: 'ios', is_verified: true}) )
```

In both situations however, you'll have to eliminate or slightly modify your second query.

[Learn more about merge here.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the merge method. Mr.Humza